# glGetUniformLocation returns -1 for USED variable, Hell with optimization

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, fragment-shader, glsles

I understand that if some `uniform` variable is not actively contributing to pipeline's output, it is optimized and it should return -1. Consider a fragment shader below.

```
const char fShader[] =  "precision mediump float;                                               \n"

    "uniform float  uGlobalTime;                                            \n"

    "const int iMaxIterations = 6;                                          \n"
    "float fCircleSize = 1.0 / (3.0 * pow(2.0, float(iMaxIterations)));     \n"

    "vec2 Rotate(vec2 uv, float a)                                          \n"
    "{                                                                      \n"
        "return vec2(uv.x * cos(a) - uv.y * sin(a), uv.y * cos(a) + uv.x * sin(a));  \n"
    "}                                                                      \n";


    "void main()                                                    \n"
    "{                                                              \n"
        "vec2 uv = vec2(1280.0, 720.0);                                             \n"
        "uv = -0.5 * (uv - 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy) / uv.x;           \n"

        "uv = Rotate(uv, uGlobalTime);                          \n"
        "uv *= sin(uGlobalTime) * 0.5 + 1.5;                        \n"

        "float s = 0.3;                                             \n"
        "for(int i = 0 ; i < iMaxIterations; ++i)                   \n"
        "{                                                          \n"
            "uv = abs(uv) - s;                                      \n"
            "uv = Rotate(uv, uGlobalTime);                      \n"
            "s = s / 2.0;                                           \n"
        "}                                                          \n"

        "float c = length(uv) > fCircleSize ? 0.0:1.0;              \n"

        "gl_FragColor = vec4(c * uGlobalTime, c * uGlobalTime, c * uGlobalTime, 1.0);                           \n"

    "}                                                              \n";
```

This sincerely tries to use passed uniform at several location, and in the final output color as well. But I am still getting -1 as return value. There is no error though. I don;t think anything wrong on my side as well.

Optimization is done, I am sure. I checked no of active uniforms, and there are 2 only. I am using 3.  BUT WHY on the earth..., is compiler blind..??
I can get around by using attribute, but why should I?

**Edit**

Please see my vertex shader as well

```
const char vShader[] =  "attribute vec3 vPosition;                                      \n"

"uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;                                        \n"
"uniform mat4 uPMatrix;                                         \n"

"void main(void)                                                \n"
"{                                                              \n"
    "gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);                     \n"
"}                                                              \n";
```

I am listing my own workaround:

adding 3 lines in vertex shader at appropriate locations:

```
"attribute float vGlobalTime                                    \n"
"varying float globalTime;                                      \n"
"globalTime = vGlobalTime;                                      \n"
```

and 1 new line in fragment shader:

```
"varying float globalTime;                                      \n"
```

And now using `globalTime` in all places where I had earlier used `uGlobalTime`

PS: I have not tested this; but I don't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: By using attribute? What attribute? Attributes are per-vertex, and this is a fragment shader. I also only see 1 uniform in your shader. Since uniform locations are a function of the _linker_, you really need to include the vertex shader in your question for proper context.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, what I am passing in uniform is time_per_frame. So passing time in vertex shader, and pipeline can provide that as an input to fragment shader. So why can't I, unless ethics deny that? The other two uniforms being `mat4 Mprojection` and `mat4 MMview`. Sorry for not mentioning it, but I have told my vertex shader here. Only multiplication of these two matrices, and `attibute vec3 aVer`

Comment: You said that if you don't use the attribute (which I assume is `aVer`) this problem occurs. If you don't use that attribute, then from the sounds of things `gl_Vertex` has no defined value and the result of the fragment shader is undefined. This is all speculation without seeing the actual vertex shader, but that is what would cause this sort of thing - undefined output in the linked vertex shader leads to a fragment shader that might as well be empty.

Comment: No sir, there is a little misunderstanding(because of me only, I was not to-the-point). Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a wild semicolon at the end of line 7 of your fragment shader C++ source string definition.

```
const char* source =
  "line 1"
  "line 2"; // <- semicolon intended?
  "line 3+ ignored"; // <- lose string constant which is never assigned to anything
```

This causes the whole main function of your fragment shader to be skipped and shouldn't even link at all. [Did you check for errors after linking your program](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Error_Checking)?

---

Think about outsourcing your shader code into an external file, which prevents typos like this and also removes the need for recompiling your application each time you change a shader.

```
bool Shader::compileFromFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream stream(filename, std::ios_base::in);
    if (!stream.is_open())
        return false;
    std::string source{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
    return compile(source);
}
```

Comment: Good eye, but I think you mean line 8 unless you started counting at 0? ;)

Comment: buhh... you are right, I should get over my laziness and put shaders in different files. Thank you so much. Just for the sake of completeness, your suggested method won't work for file'd shaders on android as files will be compressed apk(I never told before I am on Android). Asset Manager is required.